# Save Live Watch variable in IAR Workbench as LOG file

Tags: debugging, iar

I don't know if it's possible as the IAR Workbench manual doesn't cite something like that but I would like to generate some sort of LOG from the LIVE Watch variables.

For istance, if I'm live watching `var1` I would like to generate a formatted text file like:

```
16-05-2022 11:51:01 var1 120
16-05-2022 11:51:02 var1 122
16-05-2022 11:51:03 var1 116
16-05-2022 11:51:04 var1 102
```

Is there a way to do that? Or at least to read this kind of information somewhere so I can write some sort of code in python or something to read the values?

I'm using IAW Workbench 6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out there's no way to actually save the variables as LOG.

The only workaround is to use [breakpoints and macros to dump the value](https://www.iar.com/knowledge/learn/debugging/how-to-dump-variables-and-register-values-with-c-spy-macros/) but, unfortunately, this is not a solution on my end as the breakpoints need user intervention to start again the code